# Magento XML and instantiating a blogpost Model

Tags: php, magento

Very Similar [to this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190156/how-to-instantiate-a-model-in-magento) I am attempting to follow Alan Storm's [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm) to instantiate a model. I am not quite sure why It isn't working.

I followed the tutorial as closely as I could. I was able to get to the point where I got the following error:

> "Warning: include(Mage/Company/Mymodulename/Model/Artwork.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

But I've been unable to get the class name to display (see IndexController.php).

The problem comes in when I attempt to instantiate my model. I suspect the problem may be related to some minor semantics so I attempted to pay close attention to capitalization during my web sanitation process.

I could use any help offered on what I may be doing wrong?

My file structure is as follows:

```
[app]
    [code]
        [local]
            [Company]
                [MyModuleName]
                    [block]
                    [controllers]
                        IndexController.php
                    [etc]
                        config.xml
                        system.xml
                    [Helper]
                        Data.php
                    [Model]
                        Artwork.php
                    [sql]
```

My XML Is as follows:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
         <!-- ... -->
         <models>
             <MyModuleName>
                 <class>Company_MyModuleName_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>MyModuleName_mysql4</resourceModel>
             </MyModuleName>
         </models>
         <!-- ... -->
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Company_MyModuleName>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_MyModuleName</module>
                    <frontName>frontname</frontName>
                </args>
            </Company_MyModuleName>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

If my model successfully instantiates $blogpost should display my class name at http://domain.com/frontname/index/testModel.

file: app/code/local/Company/MyModuleName/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Company_MyModuleName_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function testModelAction() {
        $blogpost = Mage::getModel('company_mymodulename/artwork');
        echo get_class($blogpost);
    }
}
```

file: app/code/local/Company/MyModuleName/Model/Artwork.php

```
class Company_MyModuleName_Model_Artwork extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('company_mymodulename/artwork');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things pop out immediately.  First, I assume you're trying to instantiate the module with code that looks like this

```
Mage::getModel('company_mymodulename/artwork');
```

See the `company_mymodulename`?  That's the group name.  You want that to match your configuration.  In other words, this

```
    <models>
         <MyModuleName>
             <class>Company_MyModuleName_Model</class>
             <resourceModel>MyModuleName_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </MyModuleName>
     </models>
```

Should be this

```
    <models>
         <company_mymodulename>
             <class>Company_MyModuleName_Model</class>
             <resourceModel>company_mymodulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </company_mymodulename>
    </models>
```

Second, although technically legal, using mixed case in your module and class names (`MyModuleName`) is a bad idea.  The autoloader implementation is case sensative, and it's very easy to slightly misname something and not realize.  Stick with `Leading_Word_Case_For_Mymodulename`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I tried it a couple times with "Company_MyModuleName_Model" but never all lowercase. While I've got your attention I wanted to say thanks for all the help. I've learned more about Magento in the couple months since discovering your book/debugger than I had in the last two years. Both were well worth the investment!